# Resources to justify the use of musical instruments in an alien planet?

Tags: gas

Well, basically I was thinking on a planet where humans live above clouds/a certain atmosphere level, because down there is (darker and colder? hotter and harder to breath? full of creatures?) dangerous.
 My idea is for the place on the surface to be mainly silents, as sounds don't carry around easily (perhaps not above a certain frequency or below a decibel threshold), or perhaps the wind acted like some sort of weird natural active noise cancellation but I guess rather than muting that would be deafening.
So i'm not sure exactly... Should I pursue this idea, or is way too complicated to justify without falling into soft fantasy? For example, one could be carrying some sort of tuba and while playing at about 110db and 60hz can be heard a few dozen meters away, or perhaps an adult male with really deep voice screaming his lungs could pull it off.
So, a little help here? Thanks!

Comment: (1) Just for information, decibels are a measure of the sound pressure at the ears of the observer. (Well, actually decibels are a general way of expressing the ratio between two quatities, but that's not important here.) Sound pressure is inversely proportional to the distance from the source; so the meaning of "playing the tuba at 110 dB" depends on the distance between the tuba and the observer; each doubling of the distance reduces the sound pressure by 3 dB (if the propation medium is stationary etc.). (2) In practice one would of course use loudspeakers, not musical instruments.

Comment: do you mean/want musical as a valuable resource due to the environment you describe? or you mean as communication method ? or something ?

Comment: Yes, thats why I mentioned " few dozen meters, as it would get to aroudn 90db which is already afaik a top screaming level of noise for a person, so, in this case, even if you could be heard, is pointless if its only screaming to the point of hurting yourself and on a very close range. That was my idea at least - And yes, for comunication (basic though; military)

Answer (score 3):

**Snow.**

**[image: Snow.]**

[source](https://koaa.com/news/covering-colorado/2019/03/22/national-weather-service-wind-gust-during-blizzard-at-cos-airport-set-all-time-record/)

On the surface, it is always snowing.  The ground is warm thanks to geothermal activity and so it does not accumulate much.  But the air is always full of thick flakes and there is always a blanket of several inches on the ground.

Signal horns would be great.  Also because in the snow, visibility is even worse than sound and you can still hear a person at a distance when you can no longer see them.  Something like a vuvuzela would be key in this environment to keep track of each other.  It is very easy to get lost.

Comment: And thus was born the most annoying survival thriller ever to brighten a cinema screen.

Comment: Its awesome, but isnt there a way to do the same as with sight, but with sound? I mean, is simpler, more realistic and in practice pretty much the same but I would still want to know if theres a way to justify a drop/muffling in sound

Comment: @Simon - yeah, the sight was just a side effect.  Snow hugely muffles sound.  That is what I mean it to do in your scenario.  https://www.bustle.com/articles/137426-why-is-it-quiet-when-it-snows-its-not-just-because-everyone-is-hibernating

Comment: Snow. Or dust. Or fog.

Answer (score 2):

### A world covered in Moss and Soft Organic Aerated Tissue, with Warm Air hugging the ground and Cold Air above

Sound is essentially energy waves using vibrating air molecules as the medium. Thus anything that is soft, has lots of small air pockets inside or holes, will trap and absorb the vibrating air molecules.

Moss is a highly sound absorbent growth - so much so that it can be used as acoustic absorbers in galleries and lobbies:

[image]

Imagine all surfaces are covered in Moss - the air is moist and natural light plentiful. This blankets all rocks, plants, ground surfaces in thick organic moss-like growth that any sound wave that hits it will not be reflected, but instead completely absorbed. It would be akin to being in a Recording Studio which is completely silent:

[image]

You can also have warm air hugging the ground, and a layer of cold air above. This is the reverse of the flanking sound effect - if you've noticed at nighttime and early morning that you could hear sounds very far away this is due to sound waves being diffracted by warmer air above ensuring sound waves 'bounce' off the air and back to the ground. By reversing this, all sound will diffract 'away' from the ground and dissipate upwards. A diagram is as follows:

[image]

These will make a very very silent world on the ground.

Comment: Well, part of it would be, although I imagined it at a bigger scale (atmospheric) where the p lace under the clouds is way way warmer than  on top of the mountains where humans live. How steep should be this temeprature change and how do I ensure this drop in temperature between the same atmosphere? Also, how much quieter would this world be, is there a rough estimate I could make? (like "instead of 6db/10m, is 16db" or something like that. Also, how much quieter (the moss) than the snow it would be? Thanks i nadvance